# Obtaining DTED1 or 2?

Tags: data, download, dted

I've been looking around the internet and I can find freely available DTED0, but I am struggling to find databases for DTED1 or 2, even to purchase.  Can anyone point me at a place that sells these (or has them freely available)?  I am familiar with the USGS elevation data, but looking specifically for DTED.

Comment: For what geographic area are you looking?  The USGS hosts SRTM download from http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/ in DTED format, but higher resolution data (and sensitive locations even at lower resolution) is generally reserved for US military use (FOUO)

Comment: I was hoping for a worldwide database.  I think I found a place selling it for $94,000, but I was hoping to find a second price point to see if this was reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Level 1 and 2 are "Not releasable outside DoD unless specifically authorized by the HQ NIMA"

A number of alternate exists. As Vince states SRTM is top of the list at 90m.

My pick is ASTER at 30 m globally. http://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/gdem.asp

Comment: That explains the difficulty in finding it.  Thanks.

Comment: It is not that great anyway is the word among the analysts (as of about 2005) when I worked on some 3D models for the military.

Comment: SRTM has been updated since 2005; I imagine the others have as well.  A lot can happen in a computer decade.

Comment: The SRTM global product was updated to Version 4 was in 2006 / 2007 and fully released in 2008. No real changes since then and is still at 4.1 Some updates are planned using ASTER filling. Temporal coverage is still correctly stated as 2000.

Comment: Yeah, I was just reading an FAA advisory circular that made it sound like DTED0,1,and 2 data was required.  Not sure if it meant that resolution of data, or specifically those data sets.